# increase idle timeout for gremlin console AWS Neptune

Tags: gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

I am on ubuntu 18, I have the gremlin console always opened, after I :remote console, I run some query, then if I keep idle for like 3 mins, the connection then got dropped, then I have to exit the current connection and reconnect, which is quite annoying.

Is there a way to increase the idle timeout

basically I need to type in these command again and again.....

```
bin/gremlin.sh
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/neptune-remote.yaml
:remote console
```

Comment: Can you try with adding  keepAliveInterval property in the yaml.

Comment: It'll look something like this . connectionPool: { enableSsl: true, trustCertChainFile: "file.pem", keepAliveInterval: 360000 }

Comment: I've added a bit more context and code links and posted an answer for this, in the hope that this might help others as well. Let me know if you need more details Zhonmin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are looking for is the `keepAliveInterval` in Settings.
https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/6083dc4fcb214df64be72483f8779d81e73c0fac/gremlin-driver/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/Settings.java#L319-L324

This key is wired inside connectionPool:
https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/6083dc4fcb214df64be72483f8779d81e73c0fac/gremlin-driver/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/Settings.java#L236-L237

So, as ashoksl@ pointed out in a comment already, you need to include this setting inside your remotttte YAML conf under connectionPool.

Someething like:

```
host: localhost
port: 8182
connectionPool: {
  enableSsl: true
  ..
  ..
  keepAliveInterval: 30000
}
```

You might also want to look at this logic of server-clint ping pong for additional knobs.
https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/ad8d663ffd957df3724c7aa8fe8bb4f893d76557/gremlin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/handler/OpSelectorHandler.java#L101-L110

Hope this helps.